# ansible awx/tower command timeout

Tags: ansible

everytime a task of my playbook failed becaus it triggered the command timeout

```
command timeout triggered, timeout value is 10 secs...
```

My question is how to increase this value.
I already tried with `ansible_command_timeout: 60` in every layer (for the whole playbook, for the whole Task, for the single job)
Ive tried to change this value exporting the value to the ansible config.

```
export ANSIBLE_PERSISTENT_COMMAND_TIMEOUT=60
```

And Ive modified the value int /etc/ansible...

```
[persistent_connection]
command_timeout = 60
```

I also tried to set the variable in the "vars" section of the job Template in AWX

nothing of this helps...

then Ive tried to use the "deprecated" method adding `timeout: 60` for the job. Ansible says that this variable is deprecated and is no longer supported in future versions of ansible.

I am using AWX 9.0.1.0 including Ansible 2.8.5.
Of course i could disable the deprecation prompts but I wanted to buld a consistent playbook for updating my cisco networking devices.

In addition what makes me wondering that on the Host-Machine for my AWX container there is the version 2.9.1 of ansible installed and the ansible of the container got the version 2.8.5 but ive installed both Ansible and AWX at the same time.

I guess that the problem is that i just edited the value for connection timeout of the host-ansible and not for the container-ansible instance.
I also guess that the host-ansible installation is only used to build the AWX/Tower and the execution of the playbooks in AWX does the container-ansible instance which is ansible 2.8.5...

Is there any option to change the value of the ansible container instance via awx.
I dont want to connect to the shell of the container to editing this value because everytime i would rebould or update the AWX installation i have to change this.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with AWX but does this help? https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/4193

Comment: Its less a connection timeout. 
It is a command timeout.

Comment: Yes, but ansible_timeout is a basic ansible variable, so perhaps it works the same way: AWX_TASK_ENV['ANSIBLE_PERSISTENT_COMMAND_TIMEOUT '] = '60'

Comment: Hmm, I have neiter the folder ´/etc/tower/´ nor the folder ´/etc/awx/´ on my system so i can't edit the config file "`setting.py`"
I use awx coming in a docker container. This is the **recommended** way.